# Newest comments first not working

Tags: functions, comments, templates

I'd like to have my newest comments listed first but nothing seems to be working. In the dashboard I set

[image]

In `comments.php` I have

```
<?php wp_list_comments(array(
    'reverse_top_level' => true,
    'callback'      =>  'custom_comments_callback',
    'avatar_size'   =>  50,
    'reply_text'    =>  'Reply to this comment'
    )); ?>
```

And In `functions.php` I added

```
if (!function_exists('custom_reverse_comments')) {
    function custom_reverse_comments($comments) {
        return array_reverse($comments);
    }   
}
```

And still the oldest comments are shown on top. For an example, see this [introduction to SPSS](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-what-is-it/#comments).

Oddly, the final result is different (better but not perfect) on a local version of my website with the exact same settings/files.

Answer (score 0):

You have no need callback function. Only reverse_top_level: true is find for what you want to do. Just remove 'callback'      =>  'custom_comments_callback', from your array.

```
<?php wp_list_comments(array(
   'reverse_top_level' => true,
   'avatar_size'   =>  50,
   'reply_text'    =>  'Reply to this comment'
)); ?>
```

Comment: what about `functions.php` and the dashboard? Just removing the `callback` line doesn't help. In fact, it seems to remove some of the CSS applied to the comment list.